# Subclipse 'Mark as merged' crashes in Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, subclipse

When i 'mark as merged' a file in the Team Synchronizing perspective, a popup is shown and it says only this :

> An internal error occurred during "mark as merged".
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

And then my changes are in a new file *.tmp and the real file contains the server version.

Have you encountered this and fixed it somehow ?

*EDIT : version & stacktrace*

Versions:

- Svn 1.7.9
- Eclipse juno
- windows xp
- Subclipse 1.8.19

Stacktrace of the NPE :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.ui.operations.UpdateOperation.getSchedulingRule(UpdateOperation.java:129)
at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.ui.operations.RepositoryProviderOperation.execute(RepositoryProviderOperation.java:70)
at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.ui.operations.SVNOperation.run(SVNOperation.java:90)
at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.ui.subscriber.MarkMergedSynchronizeOperation$1.execute(MarkMergedSynchronizeOperation.java:74)
at org.eclipse.ui.actions.WorkspaceModifyOperation$1.run(WorkspaceModifyOperation.java:106)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
at org.eclipse.ui.actions.WorkspaceModifyOperation.run(WorkspaceModifyOperation.java:118)
at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.ui.repository.RepositoryManager.run(RepositoryManager.java:375)
at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.ui.subscriber.MarkMergedSynchronizeOperation$3.run(MarkMergedSynchronizeOperation.java:153)
at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.ui.subscriber.MarkMergedSynchronizeOperation$4.run(MarkMergedSynchronizeOperation.java:162)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:52)
at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.ui.subscriber.MarkMergedSynchronizeOperation.run(MarkMergedSynchronizeOperation.java:159)
at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.ui.subscriber.MarkMergedSynchronizeOperation.run(MarkMergedSynchronizeOperation.java:56)
at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.ui.subscriber.SVNSynchronizeOperation.run(SVNSynchronizeOperation.java:61)
at org.eclipse.team.internal.ui.actions.JobRunnableContext.run(JobRunnableContext.java:144)
at org.eclipse.team.internal.ui.actions.JobRunnableContext$ResourceJob.runInWorkspace(JobRunnableContext.java:72)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in Subclipse 1.8.19.

http://subclipse.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=1498

Fixed in the 1.8.20 release.  So, if possible, upgrade your Subclipse version to latest which is currently 1.8.22.

Comment: I have a prebuilt eclipse and little room for modifying it. I updated my question with the informations i could gather from the about page. And i don't know how to get the stacktrace of this exception

Comment: Well, 1.8.19 is not as bad, so that is good.  Look for the "Error Log" view if you have it.  That will show logged errors

Comment: thanks for "Error log". I didn't know. I added the stacktrace to the question

Comment: I have updated my answer based on the additional info you provided.